# Parser error in MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I converted my MVC - 3 project to MVC - 4 project by following [this tutorial.](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253806) I just created new MVC - 4 project , copy all existing controllers, views, models, contents from MVC - 3 project to newly created project. Then completed all manually conversion steps from the tutorial. Now after doing all this when i run MVC - 4 project i got this following exception page :

Can anybody please explain me how to solve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class name in the `inherits` attribute in the `Global.asax` (right click view markup) should match the class name and namespace in the `Global.asax.cs`

Right now you have

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" 
                Inherits="SiteBuilderAzure_MVC_4.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>
```

But I guess in your `Global.asax.cs` you have your MvcApplication in different namespace:

```
namespace SomeOtherNamespace
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
    }
}
```

So just make sure that you use the correct MvcApplication namespace in your `Inherits`

Comment: I encountered this when the namespace of the MvcApplication had changed, but what is in the Global.asax didn't change.

Answer (score -1):

i also facing same problem just remove unwanted file and clean the solution and rebuild it